# Only a single WITH MOVE clause should be specified for any logical file name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do a copy database by scripting a backup and restore.  I have the backup procedure working correctly but I keep getting the error

> Conflicting file relocations have been specified for file. Only a
>   single WITH MOVE clause should be specified for any logical file name.

when I run the procedure to do the restore.

Here is the procedure code.  Can anyone spot what my error is?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spDBRestore (@BackupName NVARCHAR(50), @RestoreName NVARCHAR(50))
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @BackupPath NVARCHAR(4000) = 'S:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\TemplateCopy\'+@BackupName+'.BAK',
@NewDBFileName NVARCHAR(4000) = 'S:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'+@RestoreName+'.mdf',
@NewLFFileName NVARCHAR(4000) = 'L:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\'+@RestoreName+'_1.ldf'
select @BackupName, @RestoreName, @NewDBFileName, @newlffilename
RESTORE DATABASE @RestoreName
FROM DISK = @BackupPath
WITH FILE = 1,
MOVE @BackupName TO @NewDBFileName,
MOVE @BackupName TO @NewLFFileName,
NOUNLOAD,
REPLACE;

END
```

Comment: You're moving the same thing ('@BackupName') twice

Comment: Isnt backup name supposed to be the name of the backup database?  Or do I need to specify that it is the backup databases mdf and ldf files respectively?

Comment: You move the logical file (by name). Not the backup name, nor the database name. You retrieve the name of the file(s) in the backup using [`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be moving the backup file, the `MOVE` clause takes the ***logical database file name*** as the first parameter, and then the `TO ...` is the destination physical filename for the corresponding database file.

[BOL reference on RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> **MOVE 'logical_file_name_in_backup' TO 'operating_system_file_name' [ ...n ]**
>
> Specifies that the data or log file whose logical name is specified by logical_file_name_in_backup should be moved by restoring it to the location specified by operating_system_file_name. The logical file name of a data or log file in a backup set matches its logical name in the database when the backup set was created.

You can retrieve the logical file name of the database files from [RESTORE FILELISTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (note, the `LogicalName` column in the result set).